Chrome Active Url from in latest Chrome version Not Working
I'm getting Active Google Chrome Url from the below code. In latest chrome version the code is not working and old chrome it is working .Providing the code below.
public static string ActiveChromeUrl(Process p)
{
string strUrl = "";
try
{
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
AutomationElement edit = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
if (edit != null)
{
AutomationPattern[] patterns = edit.GetSupportedPatterns();
if (patterns.Length > 0)
{
ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]); // Error Firing
strUrl = val.Current.Value;
if (Regex.IsMatch(strUrl, @"^(https://)?[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*$"))
{
if (!strUrl.StartsWith("http"))
{
strUrl = "https://" + strUrl;
}
}
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
if (ex.Message == "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern' to type 'System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern'.")
{
isChromeFault = true;
}
}
return strUrl;
}
Error firing code line
ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
I had checked in chrome version 96.0.4664.45  it is working fine . My client is using an app from 2021 onwards upto now . Recently this issue happend
